# Display the parsed JSON into html tables

Tags: php, html, json, html-table

I have tried hard in styling the JSON values that are printed randomly in page, here that are 4 categories,what I am doing with php then depending on the type id, as it is common in all array, to determine whether they belong to 0,1,2,3 category, then printing all the elements in the json array and so on, here I would like to create table for each category and push all the corresponding id's to the table rows. What I have tried so far

Comment: in which format you want ? you have any sketch how it will display.. if possible give your product registration id in question

Comment: how can i give you the layout that i wish to get

Comment: Add dummay image in your queation or print sample data as want in output

Comment: but your script is not given any response from server how can i get whole json array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not add columns "td" in you code, please put proper format to create a table.

Try to put in this format :

```
foreach($json_o[account_detail] as $type)
{
echo 'Type '.$type[type] ;
echo "<table>";
if($type[type]=='0')
{
  "<tr><td>".echo 'Name'.$type[name]."</td>";
  "<td>".echo 'Email'.$type[email_id]."</td>";
 "<td>".  echo 'Username'.$type[user_name]."</td>";
 "<td>".  echo 'Password'.$type[password]."</td>";
 "<td>".  echo 'Organisation name'.$type[org_name]."</td>";
 "<td>".  echo 'Location name'.$type[loc_name]."</td>";
 "<td>".  echo 'Building name'.$type[building_name].'."</td></tr>';     
}
.....................
..................
//remaining code in same format with columns <td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a possible solution, that's how I'm handling my json responses currently:

```
foreach($result->{'results'} as $obj){
   echo '<tr>
           <td>' . $obj->{'user_name'} .'</td>
           <td>' . $obj->{'org_name'} .'</td>
           etc...
         </tr>';
}
```